# Perl Web Login Script With CGI::Session

Tags: perl, cgi

i'm on the same problem since almost two week ago.
i'm a newbie with Perl and Web :/

i followed the CGI::Session tutorial and Cookbook, the code seems to be good but... not working.

> index.cgi

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use CGI;
use CGI::Cookie;
use HTML::Template;
use strict;
use warnings;
use CGI::Session;
use CGI::Carp qw(fatalsToBrowser);
require "cgi-bin/web_base.pl";
require "cgi-bin/login.pl";

my $cgi = new CGI;
my $session = new CGI::Session("driver:File", undef, {Directory=>'/tmp'}) or die CGI::Session->errstr;
my $CGISESSID = $session->id();
print header();
print $cgi->header();
print my_topbar();
login_attempt($session, $cgi);

if ( $session->param("~login-trials") >= 3 ) {
    print error("You failed 3 times in a row.\n" .
                "Your session is blocked. Please contact us with ".
                "the details of your action");
    exit(0);

}

unless ( $session->param("~logged-in") ) {
    print login_form($cgi, $session);
    exit(0);

}
print footer();
```

> login.cgi

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use CGI;
use CGI::Cookie;
use HTML::Template;
use CGI::Session;
use CGI::Carp qw(fatalsToBrowser);
use Fcntl;

my $cgi = new CGI;      
my $session = new CGI::Session(undef, $cgi, {Directory=>'/tmp'});
sub login_attempt {
    my ($session, $cgi) = @_;

    if ( $session->param("~logged-in") ) {
        return 1;  # Verify if user is not logged.
    }

    my $username = $cgi->param("username") or return;
    my $password=$cgi->param("password") or return;

    # Form submited. Try to load profile.

    if ( my $profile = load_profile($username, $password) ) {
        $session->param("~profile", $profile);
        $session->param("~logged-in", 1);
        print "YOUPIIIII";
        $session->clear(["~login-trials"]);
        $session->redirect("dashboard.cgi");
        return 1;
    }

    # Failed to login, wrong credentials.

    my $trials = $session->param("~login-trials") || 0;
    return $session->param("~login-trials", ++$trials);
}
return 1;

sub load_profile {
    my ($username, $password) = @_;

    local $/ = "\n";
    unless (sysopen(PROFILE, "profile.txt", O_RDONLY) ) {
        die ("Couldn't open profile.txt: $!");
    }
    while ( <PROFILE> ) {
        /^(\n|#)/ and next;
        chomp;
        my ($n, $p) = split "\s+";
        if ( ($n eq $username) && ($p eq $password) ) {
            my $p_mask = "x" . length($p);
            return {username=>$n, password=>$p_mask};

        }
    }
    close(PROFILE);
    return undef;
}
```

profile.txt

```
Formget    123
```

When i try to login, nothing happen, even when i try wrong crendentials it should block me after 3 attemps but it is not.

Can someone really help me on this ? i can't take it anymooooore.

feel free for any questions :)

EDIT :

-login_attempt() corrected

-load-profile wasn't working, made a new one, but still need improvement.

-Last Problem is session init

Comment: https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/CGI/lib/CGI.pod#CGI.pm-HAS-BEEN-REMOVED-FROM-THE-PERL-CORE

Comment: Your indentation is weird, but it looks like your login script defines a couple of subroutines … and never calls them.

Comment: That's because they get called in index.pl, which requires login.pl. We have ourselves a nice dish of spaghetti here. ;)

Comment: @simbabque oh, hello you... you made me cry last time x)

Comment: Well you seem to have made progress. That's great. :)

Comment: @simbabque ahah thx but i progress toooooo slow ><

Comment: Please include an example profile.txt that we can use to try your code.

Comment: Please consider using the safer `Class->new()` syntax in place of the `new Class` that you're using in a couple of places.

Comment: @simbabque
profile.txt is like:
username(tab)password(\n)

Comment: @simbabque profile.txt added up in post

Comment: I've just fixed the indentation in your code and I can now see that you have an extra `return 1` between the the subroutines in `login.cgi`. That will throw an error saying "Can't return outside a subroutine", so I'm getting more and more confused that you claim to see no errors at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you sure that you don't get any errors? Have you checked the web server error log?

You call `login_attempt()` with two parameters (`$session` and `$cgi`) but in login.cgi, that subroutine is defined like this:

```
sub login_attempt() {
  ...
}
```

You're (probably accidentally) using a prototype on that subroutine, telling Perl that it takes no parameters. So I'd be surprised if you don't get an error saying:

> Too many arguments for main::login_attempt

Remove the parentheses from that definition.

```
sub login_attempt {
  ...
}
```

**Update:** I think you're missing one very important step here. From the [CGI::Session Tutorial](https://metacpan.org/pod/CGI::Session::Tutorial):

> There is one small, but very important thing your application needs to perform after creating CGI::Session object as above. It needs to drop Session ID as an HTTP cookie into the user's computer. CGI::Session will use this cookie to identify the user at his/her next request and will be able to load his/her previously stored session data.
>
> To make sure CGI::Session will be able to read your cookie at next request you need to consult its name() method for cookie's suggested name:
>
> ```
> $cookie = $query->cookie( -name   => $session->name,
>                           -value  => $session->id );
> print $query->header( -cookie=>$cookie );
> ```
>
> `name()` returns CGISESSID by default. If you prefer a different cookie name, you can change it as easily too, but you have to do it before CGI::Session object is created:
>
> ```
> CGI::Session->name("SID");
> $session = CGI::Session->new();
> ```
>
> Baking the cookie wasn't too difficult, was it? But there is an even easier way to send a cookie using CGI::Session:
>
> ```
> print $session->header();
> ```
>
> The above will create the cookie using CGI::Cookie and will return proper http headers using CGI.pm's CGI method. Any arguments to CGI::Session will be passed to CGI::header().

Without this, you'll be creating a brand new session for each request.

Comment: Oh, nice idea x)
i made the change but nothing different hapend

Comment: You still haven't mentioned whether or not you're seeing any errors in the web server error log. Another possibility is the fact that you have two `$session` objects (one in each of your files). It's possible that this is confusing matters. I suggest getting it to work in a single file and only then trying to carve some of it out into a module (not another program - a real Perl module).

Comment: No error in log, the problem was comming from load_profile function,
the fact is, now i can log in, but i still not have a session. if i go again on index, it will print the login script, and "login-trials" doesn't work.
it feels like it won't save a session in cookie

Comment: As I said. I suspect the fact that you're creating two session objects is confusing matters.

Comment: should i replace one declaration of $session and $cgi in login.pl or index.cgi ? it's a bit confusing for me

Comment: I've already made a suggestion about that two comments back - "I suggest getting it to work in a single file and only then trying to carve some of it out into a module."

Comment: And note what I said above about using `Class->new()` instead of `new Class`. You had it right in your previous question. Why did you change it?

Comment: yes i don't know why i tried like that, i restarted from scratch since last time. i will try to change it back

Comment: Should i set the cookie before or after init my CGI and CGI::Session ?

Comment: At some point you're going to have to start thinking this through for yourself :-) As the cookie needs to contain the session's ID, you can't create the cookie until after you have created the session object. And if you're printing the header using the CGI object's `header()` method, it seems obvious that you can't do it until after you have created that object. Did you read the tutorial that I pointed you at?

Comment: yes, maaany times x) but i don't understand everything, english is not my main language.
i think i can haddle for the rest, my login script is fully working now, only cookies left and the web part of my project is finish \o/
ty for your help man